# jQuery code for appending table while calling setInterval

Tags: jquery

i want to call `getTestStatus` function  every `10 sec`.it is for checking if any data is exist or not, if exist fetch data and display in a table.
but what is happening in the above code table is created every 10 sec.i only want to create table based on the data fetched.(my loop contains 3 values only.)

```
interval = setInterval(function () {
      getTestStatus(len, $('#server').val());
    },1000);
```

...

```
   function getTestStatus(len, server) {
    var  string1 = '<table border="1"><tr><td>No</td><td>Testcase</td> <td>OS</td> <td>Browser</td> <td>Steps</td> <td>Result</td></tr><!--REPORT_BODY--></table>'; 
      $.ajax({
        url: '/getReports',
        cache: false
      }).done(function (html) {
        if (html != "") {
          $('#testResult').show();  
          $.each(html, function (i, data) {
    string1 + = '<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td rowspan="3">' + data.status.test + '</td><td rowspan="3"><!--OS--></td><td>' + data.status.bwser + '</td> <td> ' + data.status.report + ' </td></tr>';

     });
       $('#testResult').append( string1 );
        }

      }).fail(function () {   
        $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
      });
    }

<div id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px; "></div>
```

Comment: `html != ""` is definitely not going to ensure this. try alerting html value and see whats coming if html is not valid html.

Comment: values are getting properly..

Comment: in any case does alert come blank??

Comment: no..values are aleting with out any blankl

Comment: am getting values but every 10 secs values are appending...

Comment: can you log the html in console and see when its coming blank

Comment: actulay my pblm is table is created every 10secs...i want o create table based uopn the data fetched.i have only 3 fetched data

Comment: what is the html value for rest 7\

Answer (score 1):

You dont have create the table each time, you can just update the body part of table on each ajax call. Also specify the `dataType:json`, since you are expecting json data from server.

HTML

```
<table border="1" id="reportTab">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>No</th>
     <th>Testcase</th> 
     <th>OS</th> 
     <th>Browser</th> 
     <th>Steps</th> 
     <th>Result</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

JS function

```
function getTestStatus(len, server,string1) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/getReports',
        cache: false
      }).done(function (html) {
        if (html != "") {
         var string1 = '';
          $('#testResult').show();  
          $.each(html, function (i, data) {
    string1 + = '<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td rowspan="3">' + data.status.test + '</td><td rowspan="3"><!--OS--></td><td>' + data.status.bwser + '</td> <td> ' + data.status.report + ' </td></tr>';

     });
       $("#reportTab > tbody").html("");//clear the tbody
       $('#reportTab > tbody').append( string1 );//append the new data
        }

      }).fail(function () {   
        $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
      });
    }
```

Comment: Actually i want to append the table to div like ` $('#testResult').append( string1 );`

Comment: any other ways to add table to string variable with out putPut the table's html code inside div

Comment: yes your function already do this. use html instead of append `('#testResult').html( string1 );`

Comment: but it is not working..will u please update ur answer with that also

Comment: your code is working fine for me.but i need to place table to a string variable

Comment: What is not working?. please try to explain with detail

Comment: i put `var string1 ='<table border="1" id="reportTab"> <thead><tr><td>No</td><td>Testcase</td> <td>OS</td> <td>Browser</td> <td>Steps</td> <td>Result</td></tr> <thead><tbody> </tbody><!--REPORT_BODY--></table>'` it is not working

Comment: in your answer where i put this `('#testResult').html( string1 ); ``

Answer (score 1):

Several problems with your code.

1. It's not good to use `$.each` for plain `html` data. Using JSON data format is much better.
2. It's not good to create a new table each time you ping a script - it's a nightmare performance-wise. So, what you should do is to create your table statically and only add new rows.
3. What you do now - is just get every report and insert them to the table. Maybe you can do something, to determine only new reports on your server?

Anyway, the fastest solution without changing server-side code is:

```
<script>
     // Why do you pass parameters, if you don't use any of them?
     function getTestStatus() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/getReports",
           cache: false,
           dataType: "JSON"
        }).done(function(response){
            var thead = $("</thead>").html("<tr><th>No</th><th>Testcase</th><th>OS</th><th>Browser</th><th>Steps</th><th>Result</th></tr>");
            var tbody = $("</tbody>").html(
               $.map(response, function(data, index){
                  return '<tr><td rowspan="3">'+index+'</td><td rowspan="3">' + data.status.test + '</td><td rowspan="3"><!--OS--></td><td>' + data.status.bwser + '</td> <td> ' + data.status.report + ' </td></tr>';
               });
            );
            var table = $("</table>").append(thead).append(tbody);
            $("#testResult").html(table);
        }).fail({

            //if no report -- hide the table

            $("#testResult").html("");

            $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");                
        });
     }      
</script>
```

When you specify `"json"` as `dataType` you will trigger `done()` only if your response is a JSON value, and fail otherwise, which is far better than checking for your response to not be empty;

Server side you can use `json_encode` to provide proper response if you're using PHP, other languages have similar functions too.

Comment: any other ways to add table to string variable with out putPut the table's html code inside div

Comment: Edited for your needs.